# stopping embedded video using divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page consists of an embedded video that floats in on a div animation, with a little X in the top right corner to close it off, but when i hit the little X it continues to play because the little X only hides the video, sending it back to its original position, but I want to silence it when it's sent back.

I've tried every combination to try and get it to deleteVideo() using onClick, but nothing is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function deleteVideo() {
    document.getElementById('VideoPlayer').src = '';
  }
</script>

<a class="closeX" id="closeX" onclick="deleteVideo()";></a>
```

I'll admit I'm useless when it comes to javascript and jQuery, I can't even tell the difference.

The original looks like this:

```
<div class="dark" id="dark" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="box" id="box">
  <a class="closeX" id="closeX" onclick="deleteVideo()";></a>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/video?;start=972&amp;end=1507" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div id="Title">Video Title</div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#action').click(function(){
        $('#dark').fadeIn('fast',function(){
          $('#box').animate({'top':'120px'},500);
        });
      });

      $('#closeX').click(function(){
        $('#box').animate({'top':'-500px'},500,function(){
          $('#dark').fadeOut('fast');
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I'm suspecting this last bit is in the wrong place. Its sat below the code above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function deleteVideo() {
    document.getElementById('VideoPlayer').src='';
  }
</script>
```

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nothing in this code has an id of `VideoPlayer`

Comment: I used this to sort of help, but I got confused: <script type="text/javascript">
function deleteVideo()
{
document.getElementById('VideoPlayer').src='';
}</script> <p onclick="LoadVideo()">LOAD VIDEO</p>

Comment: @ChrisJones, check out my answer. It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make two small changes and you are good to go:

Change 1: Add one `id` attribute to your iframe tag like given below

```
<iframe width="560" **id="VideoPlayer"** height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/video?;start=972&amp;end=1507" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Change 2: Update the jquery function to call the

```
$('#closeX').click(function(){
      $('#box').animate({'top':'-500px'},500,function(){
          $('#dark').fadeOut('fast');
          deleteVideo();    // This will call the function you have defined above.
      });
});
```